# unable to download link from mobile device

Tags: codenameone

1. I am unable to download apk file link from build server on mobile device, does it has to do anything with pro feature ? Link is downloadable on desktop.
2. Is there any preference for building app for pro/free account ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enabled install from external sources you can also have the link emailed to you (with the envelope button) there is no such limit for free users.

The second question is unclear. Builds for paying users are faster based on their pay grade (less time queued) there are also some features only available for paying users see: http://www.codenameone.com/pricing.html